# Catchall 301 redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've been informed that all the press releases I've been posting to my site are showing as duplicate content so I want to redirect all posts in here to my homepage

For example I want

/press-releases/unconscious-bias-against-disabled-people-is-higher-now-than-before-the-paralympics/

To redirect to 
/

I've tried searching for the answer on google and using methods like

```
RewriteRule ^press-releases/(.*)$ http://www.ablemagazine.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

and

```
Redirect 301 /press-releases/?(.*) http://ablemagazine.co.uk/
```

But neither of those seem right. Any help appreciated

Comment: Solved in thanks to #httpd on freenode

Correct usage is:



    RedirectMatch ^/press-releases/.* http://www.ablemagazine.co.uk/